# Unity button doesn't behave as it was clicked after a click and drag

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a simple button in our application which when is pressed works just as expected, but with a light quick touch it just greys out and does nothing.

Is there a way to capture those light touches too?

**EDIT:**
I see now when exactly it doesn't work and it is when I tap, drag and release. (even if I tap, drag and don't leave the button area)

Comment: It can be either device specific or Unity3D bug that dosn't invoke OnPointerUp. Hard to say. In both cases - you cannot capture it. Unless you write custom EventManager.

Comment: Is this on PC, Mac or mobile?

Comment: It's only on an Android phone (haven't tried on any other phone though).

Comment: Try to un-check *Force Module Active* checkbox on *Touch Input Module* component of *Event System* object. let me know if this works?

Comment: I've just realized it doesn't have a Touch Input Module... Let me try to see if it has fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [EventSystem.pixelDragThreshold](http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-pixelDragThreshold.html) to a higher value. This threshold makes the difference between a click and a drag, and it's default value is quite low for high-res touch systems.